# @selector key word in iPhone programming

Tags: iphone

-(void)displayNameBy:(NSString*)name{

```
    mylable.text = name;

}
```

i want call this method using @selector keywords.

eg:

```
[MyButton addTarget:self action:***@selector(displayNameBy:name)*** forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Here bold italics  is my doubt.. could i pass name parameter from here. when i try to  pass name value i getting error.

any way to get name value in the displayNameBy:name method . using @selector key words.

here MyButton i created by programatically . not in interface builder.

**thanks and regards**

Answer (score 4):

Have an intermediate method.
like:

```
{
   ...
   [MyButton addTarget:self action:@selector(displayName) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
   ...
}

-(void) displayName
{
   [self performSelector:@selector(displayNameBy:) withObject:@"name"];
}

-(void)displayNameBy:(NSString*)name{

    mylable.text = name;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you create a one-argument selector for your action (like you're doing in `displayNameBy:`), the argument is the sender of the action. In this case, your button instance.

According to the [UIControl docs](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIControl_Class/), there are three different types of supported selectors:

```
- (void)action
- (void)action:(id)sender
- (void)action:(id)sender forEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

Where are you expecting `name` to be defined? Is it based on the user's actions, the app state, or something else? Depending on what method is used, you could create a UIButton subclass that includes either the necessary logic or declares a delegate protocol, set the delegate to your view controller, and have the delegate implementation set the button's label. The latter is probably better from a MVC standpoint, unless the source of `name` is blindingly simply (ie, an attribute that could be set on the button, not something the button would have to calculate based on other application state).

Answer (score 1):

The method's selector is just `displayNameBy:`. The `name` it the end is the name of the parameter. However, I don't know where you're expecting this `NSString *name` parameter to come from. The argument for an action method is the sender, which will be the button in this case. So it would be `- (void)displayNameBy:(id)sender`.

If you're trying to pass the parameter through the selector, that isn't possible. A selector is literally just a name — it doesn't specify any particular behavior.

If you wanted to use [PLBlocks](http://code.google.com/p/plblocks/), you could create a trampoline class that would be called like:

```
[myButton setTarget:[BlockProxy proxyWithBlock:^{ [self displayNameBy:name]; }] action:@selector(call:)  forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

That's the closest you'll get, I think. Because what you really want is for the button to call a closure, which is what PLBlocks gives you. Whether it's worth the trouble to get this kind of expressiveness is you're call.

Comment: Thanks, 
i konw this,"(void)displayNameBy:(id)sender" , but i want get the value of name here, is there any way to this. ?