# How to pass parameters using @selector

Tags: objective-c, selector, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

I need to pass parameters with @selector and here is the method that i need to call using selector:

```
-(void)clickedInfo:(NSString *)itemIndex{
// some work with itemIndex
}
```

I know that what i can do is to use an intermediate method as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2368966/selector-key-word-in-iphone-programming/2372828#2372828).

This approach doesn't work in my case because im adding the target to the uibutton in the cellForItemAtIndexPath method for the collectionView.

The parameter that i need to pass to the clickedInfo method is indexPath.row
and i can not obtain this parameter in an intermediate method.

Thanx in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `performSelector:withObject:` selector to pass an object.

Example:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(clickedInfo:) withObject:myIndex];

- (void) clickedInfo:(NSString *)itemIndex{
// some work with itemIndex
}
```

Edit: Should be just `@selector(clickedInfo:)` rather than what I had before.

Edit: Using @newacct 's suggestion, I'd recommend doing something similar to the following:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath)indexPath
{
    button.tag = indexPath.row;
    [button performSelector:@selector(clickedInfo:)];
    // or
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(clickedInfo:) forControlEvents:UITouchUpInside];
}

- (void) clickedInfo:(id)sender
{
    int row = sender.tag;
    // Do stuff with the button and data
}
```

Comment: You're right it was incorrect, updated my answer but someone else has already given the same example.

Comment: the question indicates they want to set up the action for a button

Comment: Well would the button be holding the object? Otherwise what he wants isn't really possible. I thought he said he was doing this in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method.

Comment: @EricAmorde: Yes, he is doing this in `cellForRow...` to set up a cell, which probably contains a button on which he wants to set up the action.

Comment: i did what you explained in a bit difference, difference is that i used titlelabel of the uibutton not the tag since i needed to store a string. your code helped thanx

Comment: Ah, that works too as long as that's what you want the title of the button to be. Glad you figured that out! Thanks to @newacct for the suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

So you want to store some information that can be accessed by the action of a button. Some options are:

- Use the tag property of the control. (can only store an integer)
- Subclass UIButton and use that class for the button. The class can have a field that stores the information.
- Use associated objects (associative references) to attach an object to the button. This is the most general solution.

Comment: The tag property seems like a good idea for what he wants. Just set the tag to `indexPath.row` instead of passing that as a parameter.

Comment: i used the titlelabel field of the uibutton to store string value since i dont have to display anything using that. thanx

Answer (score 1):

this is addressed lots of places, but it is easier to answer than to point you there:

```
[someObject performSelector:@selector(clickedInfo:) withObject:someOtherObject];
```

where `someObject` is the receiver and `someOtherObject` is the parameter passed to `clickedInfo`

Comment: the question indicates they want to set up the action for a button